# Ошибка авторизации (токена) vk api

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Делаю запрос:

```
group_api_url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/groups.getMembers?group_id='
id_api_url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/friends.get?user_id='
fields = '&fields=sex,bdate,city,country'
count = '&count=1000'
offset = '&offset='
token = '&token=самтокен'

def extract_members(group_id):

    list_of_members = []
    
    for offset_number in range(0, 10000, 1000):
        url = group_api_url + str(group_id) + offset + token + str(offset_number) + count + fields
        json_response = requests.get(url).json()
        #users = json_response['response']['users']
        #list_of_members += users
        
    return json_response
```

Получаю ошибку авторизации, хотя токен указан:

```
{'error': {'error_code': 5,
  'error_msg': 'User authorization failed: no access_token passed.',
```

Как исправить?

Comment: Зеленым по серому же написано - "no `access_token` passed"

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ценный комментарий, но глупый вопрос - тоже вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем коде, параметр token должен быть изменен на access_token.

Comment: `token = '&access_token=самтокен'`

Comment: Всем спасибо - вопрос с токеном решён!